# angular 2 - ngx-bootstrap show error/alert/confirm modal on ajax call

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to show modals for error/confirm/alert based on the results i get from ajax call.

Component with Ajax call -

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeValues();
}

initializeValues = function () {
    this._dataService.post("getInfoByUser", request, null).subscribe(data => 
    {...}, error => {
        this._modalService.showError(Constants.TECH_EXCEPTION);
    }); 
}
```

Modal Service -

```
export class ModalService {

  _pbModal: PubSubService = this.pubSubServiceModal;

  constructor( @Inject(PubSubService) private pubSubServiceModal){
  pubSubServiceModal.subjects = new Map<string, Subject<Modal>>();
  }

  showError(msg: string){
  var modal = new Modal(Constants.ERROR,msg);
  var data = { key: "showModal", value: modal };
    this._pbModal.publish(data); 
  }

  showAlert(msg: string){}
  ...
```

Modal Component -

```
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
export class ModalComponent {
...
@ViewChild('appModal') appModal: ModalDirective;
showModal() {
    this.appModal.show();
}
```

Modal Component HTML -

```
<div  id="modalDialog001-alert" class="modal fade" bsModal #appModal="bs-modal" [config]="{backdrop: ''}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" style="top:10%">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header padding-5">
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="close()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h3 class="modal-title">Sample Modal</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <ng-content select=".modal-body"> </ng-content>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align:right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="confirmClick()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> Ok</i></button>
    <button *ngIf="showConfirm" class="btn btn-default" (click)="close()" type="button">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Invoking Component (which passes Modal Body content) -

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('appModal') appModal: ModalComponent;
showConfirm: boolean = false;
error: string = Constants.ERROR;
alert: string = Constants.ALERT;
type: string;
msg: string;

constructor(private _modalService: ModalService,private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {   
this._modalService._pbModal.subscribe("showModal").subscribe({ next: (modal: Modal) => this.showModal(modal) });
}

showModal(modal) {
    this.msg = modal.msg;
    this.type = modal.type;
    this.showConfirm = true;
    this.appModal.showModal(); // **Throws error here - this.appModal is undefined here and I'm not able to call showModal of Modal Component**
 }
...
```

AppComponent HTML -

```
<app-modal>
 <div class="modal-body">
  <span class="glyphicon sb-alert-icon" [ngClass]="{ 'glyphicon-remove-sign text-danger': (type == error),'glyphicon glyphicon-alert text-warning': (type == alert) }" >{{msg}}</span>
 </div>
</app-modal>
```

I get following error for below lines of code in invoking component -

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'showModal' of undefined

```
this.appModal.showModal(modal);
```

Tried to add this line in ngAfterViewInit() of appcomponent, but didnt work. Please let me know how i can invoke methods of Modalcomponent from Appcomponent in my case.

**UPDATE**

Following line in appcomponent.html caused the issue -

```
<app-modal>
```

I added following and modal showed up -

```
<app-modal #appModal>
```

However, i see glyphicon css not getting rendered correctly.

I could make this working for Modals of Alert,Error,Info (with CSS issue though). But for 'Confirm'modal,i would need to display both OK & Cancel button which i was earlier doing using *ngIf. Now that I'm rendering Body content separately, how can i dsiplay button in footer for 'Confirm' modal alone? Looks like i would need to change the way I 'm doing currently, but not sure how.

Comment: have you used `selector: "app-modal"` in the modal component .ts? If yes, you should use: `@ViewChild('app-modal') appModal: ModalComponent;` in AppComponent. Give it a try